# Inequality for second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds

Suppose that all eigenvalues of the second fundamental form $A=\{h_{ij}\}$ of manifold $M$ are strictly positive, then there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that the inequality 
$$h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$$
holds everywhere on M, where $H=tr_{g}A$

My proof is as follows:

select $\epsilon$ such that $1>n\epsilon$. Since $g^{ij}g_{ij}=n$, we have $1>g^{ij}g_{ij}\epsilon$. Since all eigenvalues are strictly positive, $H$ is strictly positive as well as the trace of the matrix is equal to the sum of eigenvalues. Thus, we can multiply $1>g^{ij}g_{ij}\epsilon$ by $H$:
$$H>Hg^{ij}g_{ij}\epsilon.$$
Since $H=g^{ij}h_{ij}$, we have
$$g^{ij}h_{ij}>Hg^{ij}g_{ij}\epsilon.$$
Then
$$g^{ij}(h_{ij}-Hg_{ij}\epsilon)>0.$$
We thus conclude that $h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$.

The proof seems like a valid one. I cannot poke any holes in it. But it seems a bit ad hoc. I first took the inequality that I'm supposed to prove $h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$. Then took a trace of both sides, getting $H>\epsilon H n$, from which we get inequality $1> n\epsilon$. And then I proceeded in a somewhat backwards manner. I chose $\epsilon$ such that $1> n\epsilon$. The rest is above.

So I'm wondering if there is a proof such that inequality would follow from general differential geometric considerations rather than being a consequence of my rather ad hoc proof?

EDIT: I was wrong by concluding that $g^{ij}(h_{ij}-Hg_{ij}\epsilon)>0$ implies $h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$. But then I don't know how to finish my proof.

Comment: I don't understand what the inequality $h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$ means. Does it mean that the tensor $A - \epsilon Hg$ is positive definite? Or does it mean that in every coordinate system and for each $i$ and $j$, the inequality is true? Also, at the end of your proof, what is your reasoning to get from $g^{ij}(h_{ij}-Hg_{ij}n\epsilon)>0$ to $h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$? (Of course, I should probably understand what you're trying to prove before I understand the reasoning.)

Comment: @PhillipAndreae The inequality holds in any coordinate system and for each $i, j$. Now that you mentioned the end of the proof. I look at it and see that the conclusion was to soon. But don't know then how to finaly prove it.

Comment: @Tomas: are you sure? This interpretation seems very unlikely to me - there are plenty of symmetric matrices that have positive eigenvalues but some negative entries.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Do you mean that the inequality $h_{ij}>\epsilon Hg_{ij}$ should be interpreted as positive definiteness of the tensor $A-\epsilon Hg$?

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, or equivalently $\forall \xi . A(\xi,\xi) > \epsilon H g(\xi,\xi)$. This is the standard "ordering" on bilinear forms and is usually just written $A > \epsilon H g$; but some authors never want to write a tensor without indices. Is there a paper you're following here?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yes, the paper is "Flow by mean curvature of convex surfaces into spheres" by G. Huisken and the inequality on the page 241 at the top of the page.

Comment: @Tomas: Huisken does indeed use $A_{ij} > B_{ij}$ to mean that $A-B$ is positive definite. You can work this out later on page 245 when he clearly uses $M_{ij} \ge 0$ to mean $M$ is positive definite - the null-eigenvector condition in the assumptions for Hamilton's maximum principle makes it clear this is what is meant. (Hamilton also used this less-than-transparent notation in his original papers on the Ricci flow, which heavily inspired Huisken's work on MCF.)

Answer (score 1):

Fix a point $p\in M$. The second fundamental form at $p$ is a symmetric bilinear form, so by the spectral theorem there is an orthonormal basis $e_i$ for $T_p M$ made up of its eigenvectors; i.e. such that $A(e_i, e_j) = \lambda_i \delta_{ij} $. In this basis the matrix for $A$ is simply its eigenvalues on the diagonal and $g$ is the identity matrix, so we have $A \ge (\min_i \lambda_i) g$. From here (and the positivity assumption) we can easily get the pointwise inequality with $$\epsilon(p) = \frac12\frac{\min_i \lambda_i}{\sum_i \lambda_i}.$$

The remaining issue is whether this ratio is bounded away from zero so that we can choose $\epsilon = \inf_{p\in M} \epsilon(p)>0$. For non-compact $M$ it is possible that as we head off to infinity this ratio can approach zero - while I haven't worked out the details I think the surface of revolution of $e^{-x}$ is a counterexample. Thus you need some extra assumption - for example that the eigenvalues are bounded below by a positive constant, or compactness of $M$.

Comment: Yes, the additional assumption is that the manifold is compact. Forgot to mention than in my question.